# How can I use a variable from a received messaged in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

This is one of my very first HTML webpages projects. Long story short, I have an iframe inside the webpage which i need a button to download an svg created by the user in the webpage. I already have the download part figured out, my problem is in receiving the message and passing it to the download function. I already changed the download function to a print to see if the iframe is receiving the correct message, and it is. However, when i use the download function, it says that received data is not defined. Any help is greatly appreci

```js
window.onmessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data) {
    let receivedData = event.data;
  }
};

function downloadSVG() {
  let svgData = receivedData;

  /// Create a fake <a> element
  let fakeLink = document.createElement("a");
  /// Add image data as href
  fakeLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgData));
  /// Add download attribute
  fakeLink.setAttribute('download', 'imageName.svg');
  /// Simulate click
  fakeLink.click();

}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: downloadSVG();">download SVG</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an issue with scoping, you need to declare 'receivedData' outside of 'window.onmessage' handler. Just declare it right before 'window.onmessage' like this

```
let receivedData = null;
window.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data) {
        receivedData = event.data;
    }
};
```

**Update #0**

Here is the replacement for your 'a'-tag, to make it a button

`<button id='downloadSVG' type="button" onclick="downloadSVG()" disabled>download SVG</button>`

```
let receivedData = null;
window.onmessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data) {
    // once the data is received - get the button by ID
    const button = document.querySelector('#downloadSVG')
    // activate the button
    button.disabled = false
    receivedData = event.data;
  }
};

function downloadSVG() {
  let svgData = receivedData; 
  /// Create a fake <a> element
  let fakeLink = document.createElement("a");
  /// Add image data as href
  fakeLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgData));
  /// Add download attribute
  fakeLink.setAttribute('download', 'imageName.svg');
  /// Simulate click
  fakeLink.click();

}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very mucho!! I tried your solution, however, when I download the file and open it in notepad, it is supposed to have the message received, but instead it just says "null". What do you think is happening? Is there some type of logic and order I have to follow? I am sorry if this questions seem basic, I am just starting out with programming.

Comment: update: I tried adding a console.log(event.data) between the if statement and receivedData, and it actually shows the message received.

Comment: That is fine.
Yes, there is an order.
1) You need to receive a message from your iframe, which will trigger "window.onmessage" event handler, if you see the data between IF statement and receivedData - then the message is successfully passed
2) as soon as you received the message, you can click your button which will run 
"downloadSVG()" and you should see the data inside your file

Side note: in order to trigger message event - you can use
```
window.postMessage({data:"test"}, "*" );
```

Comment: I appreciate it very much. The message is not being sent by the iframe, the iframe is receiving it, and the button that triggers the downloadSVG() is inside the iframe html code, but outside the script tags. How can I make sure that the button is available once the message has been received and correctly declared as the received data variable.

Comment: update 2: i added console logs before and after I let receivedData = event.data inside the window.onmessage , And before and after I let svgData = receivedData inside the downloadSVG() function. The consolelogs inside the window.onmessage are correct, but the onces inside the downloadSVG function are showing null. Is it possible that when I let receivedData = event.data the scope of that variable is local?

Comment: I updated my answer and added new code, please review it, and let me know if you have new questions. I disabled a button by default, and activate it only in case if data is reseived

Comment: Hello, it works flawlessly now. Thank you very much for all of your support. I wish you luck in all of your projects.

Comment: I'm glad that I was helpful. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The variable receiveData is declared with let keyword, it will local scope. If you required is another method then use declared it outside the method.

```
let receivedData;
window.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data) {
            receivedData = event.data;
        }
    };

function downloadSVG() {
    let svgData = receivedData;

    /// Create a fake <a> element
    let fakeLink = document.createElement("a");
    /// Add image data as href
    fakeLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(svgData));
    /// Add download attribute
    fakeLink.setAttribute('download', 'imageName.svg');
    /// Simulate click
    fakeLink.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your comment. I tried your suggestions and it is not giving me an error anymore. However, when I download the file and open it in the notepad, it is supposed to show the message received, but instead it is says undefined. What do you think is happening?

Comment: update: I tried adding a console.log(event.data) between the if statement and receivedData, and it actually shows the message received.